# occasional boot fail because of error in starting Network Manager

Tags: ubuntu, boot, networkmanager

I'm working in ubuntu 18.04 in a stationary Dell computer.  Lately I have had a problem at booting where there is an error saying:

[FAILED] Failed to start network Manager
See 'systemctl status NetworkManager.service' for details
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait online

After this it seems like it's trying to restart network manager, all the messages are [OK] and the error apperars again. THe strange thing is that this error has appeared before, but after restarting the computer enough number of times (when sometimes a dev sda1 error shows instead) the computer usually starts, and it works just fine. Usually I reboot using the restart option in my GUI. Once every now and then I've shut down and restarted using the physical button on the machine. (I know it's prob not the best thing to do, but if the computer freezes up you don't have much options).

One time after starting, the Network manager indeed didn't work, but then I restarted it through the terminal and everything was fine after that.  (I wrote the commands down but of course they are in the non-starting computer now.. I can try to figure it out if it's interesting). This thing with "it can start sometimes" I strange I think. However, this time it doesn't start, so now I need to sort this out.

I tried booting into terminal by pressing down the shift key to access grub as described here: https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/ however, it does not work for me. I only end up with the same error messages. Further down in the link they then give me plenty of options for reinstalling and repairing. But I'm hesitant to use them and which to use since the computer sometimes is starting.

Comment: Same thing happened with me right now, and i can not boot after ubuntu 18.04 did some updates. i stuck to black screen and thous error messages, and only option i have to shut down.

Comment: This was long ago @SergheiLeonenco, so I can't remember exactly what I did to solve this, but I really think that I re-installed the computer. Something was broken inside the linux file structure, some corrupted file or so. I'm not good enough to fix that, so I created a linux live USB stick, extracted all my important files to an external hard drive, and re-installed the whole system. However, you can do some reparations via the linux-live USB as well, but as I said, I'm not linux-smart enough yet ... ;)